# merging matched lines with sed

Tags: sed

I saw some answers here, but can't make them work for me.
I have text like this:

```
line1
line2 text=^M
line3
line4
```

basically what i need is to replace `=^M\n` with empty character something like `s/=^M\n//`, so the output is (^M is special character ctrl+v ctrl+m)

```
line1
line2 textline3
line4
```

I know it's some sed branches but I have problem with making them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
$ sed '/^M/{N;s/=^M\n//;}' file
line1
line2 textline3
line4
```

Where ^M has to be typed as: Ctrl-V + Ctrl-M

Answer (score 1):

awk solution for this

```
 #awk -f myawk.sh temp.txt
   BEGIN { print "Start Records"}
   {
       if ($2 ~ /=\^M/){
           a=$1;
           gsub("=\\^M","",$2);
           b=$2; f=1
       }
       else {
          if(f==1){
              print a""b""$0;
              a="";
              b="";
          }else{
          print $0
          }
      }
  }
  END {print "Process Complete"}
```